# Overvoltage Clamping protection for Boost Converter

Tags: boost, esd, lead-acid, over-voltage-protection, transient-suppression

I think my circuit is failing because of ESD and/or transients when initially connecting my device to a supply.  How should I go about protecting the gate of M1?  What's the best way to clamp the input voltage to this boost converter?

I am currently working on debugging a boost converter that keeps failing out in the field.  The converter is built around the [LT1930 Boost Converter IC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1930f.pdf).  I have configured it to step-up from a 12V lead-acid battery source up to the 20V required for our load which draws 125mA.  The boost IC can be enabled and disabled using an external high-side MOSFET switch. VIN, EN, VOUT, and GND all come off the board with screw terminals.  You can see my model below.

[image: SPICE MODEL OF BOOST CIRCUIT]

These boards are in a waterproof case, but left outside in the forest near rivers and streams.  I've checked the interior but there does not appear to be any water damage inside.  I've also had these boards fail inside as well.  When they fail, M1's gate and source appear to short in one direction but not the other (like a diode).  The actual boost IC also appears to be damaged as the board no longer switches.

When probing around the board in normal operation, none of the maximum voltages on any pins appear to be exceeded.  I've also verified that M1 is indeed the BSS123 by testing its absolute parameters (I thought maybe I had received a counterfeit).  I also measured the transients on VIN and they were never more than +/-2V for more than 100uS when other devices connected to the same source battery are being turned on and off.  I am aware that since I am connected directly to a lead-acid battery, that the source voltage could be as high as ~15V when charging but the maximum input for the LT1930 is 16V.  I've also probed the output voltage and it appears to be overdamped (no transients).

I am out of ideas for what could be causing the failure and best guess now is ESD or an unexpected transient from something WILD.  I plan to make the following changes to provide overvoltage/ESD protection on the gate of M1 by connecting a 10V zener and increasing the gate resistor from 10 Ω to 10 kΩ.  I'm also going to clamp the input voltage of the LT1930 in the case of transients from source with a 15V 5W power zener are the reason that is failing as well.  I'm not sure if this is the best solution and any input is greatly appreciated.

[image: Proposed solution schematic]

If anyone would like the sim, I can send it - just ask.

Comment: D1 Zener is a good idea.  D2 BAT54 us too small.  Use a 1A diode.  The startup current is large.  L1 10uA use a 1A inductor.  Are any of the parts running hot or warm?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to show the layout and a photo of the wiring. I'm thinking about a LC resonance between C2 and the wiring inductance.

Comment: @ronsimpson Hello Ron, good catch!  Actually, the diode on the real board is the MBR0520-TP.  Sorry about that.  I will update the picture.  I haven't noticed anything heating up on failture.

Comment: @bobflux The wire feeding into vin can be up to about a meter and between 22awg to 18 awg.  VIN trace length is about 16mm with trace width of ~2.5mm.  Trace length between C2 and the drain of M2 is about 8mm and trace width of 0.5mm.

Comment: I'd add an electrolytic in parallel with C2, like 100µF, to dampen the resonance between wire inductance and C2.

Comment: Hello Everyone, just wanted to give an update.  With the changes made on we've been running the board for over a week with no issue!  Not definitive but certainly encouraging.     Another thing I could try (and probably just a good idea) is to add an actual ESD capacitor or two on VIN (between the source and the pmostfet) and maybe an electrolytic.  There are no caps there...

Comment: Howdy folks, just thought it would be fun to share the effect of adding D3 IRL.  For this test, I set V1 to 5V to turn on M1 & M2.  Then I pulsed 30V on Vin (charged up a 4x22mF caps).  [Here you can see without D3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPf5W.png).  And [here you can see after D3 was added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ3rS.png).  The 30V pulse gets suppressed down to 20V and the rate of discharge of the cap is more aggressive.  In an ideal world, D3 would have a steeper curve such that it's impedance clamped under 16V.  Right now I have BZX85B15 on there. [Edited to "SE" Imgur image links]

Comment: @ZacharyAnderson - Hi, (a) I've changed the image links in your comment above, from "public" Imgur links, to "SE" Imgur links. Please avoid public Imgur as they now delete anonymous uploads after a while. (b) If you want to include an image in a *comment*, use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. (c) FYI if you solve your own question, you can [write your own answer](/help/self-answer) (and áccept it, if no-one writes a better one for you to áccept).

Comment: Thank you for your edit Sam!

Comment: @ZacharyAnderson - You're welcome :) I just wanted to explain what I'd done & why. Mods rarely edit comments - but since Imgur now delete less active images from their "public" servers, I was worried that we might lose your images if we left them there. || FYI if you have new info which might help someone to write an answer, you can [add it into the question](/help/no-one-answers) (this bumps it on the front page). || If you make a note of the link for the "how to add an image into a comment" technique, then I can delete my earlier comment (and this one) to reduce the distraction here. Thanks!